# Can I populate Enum with For in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I'm working with Asp.net and MVC, creating a code where the person needs to enter month and year to perform a search.
I created an Enum for the months of the Year, but I can't find it "right" to create an Enum for the years, as I would have to manually populate and each year add a new value.

In my Cshtml I had done it that way

```
<select name="ano">

  @for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i > 1999; i--)
  {
    <option>@i</option>
  }
</select>
```

But to go to the MVC standard, I wanted to put this information in an Enum inside my Model. Can I do something similar to dynamically place the years in an Enum?

Comment: Why do you want an enum for year instead of int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To approach to MVC standarts , you don't need to create any enums, you have to create a model

```
public ViewModel 
{
  public int Year {get;set;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Years {get; set;}
}
```

and controller action

```
public ActionResult GetYear()
{
  var years = new List<SelectListItem>();

  for (var i = DateTime.Now.Year; i >= 1999 ; i--)
     years.Add ( new SelectListItem { Value=i.ToString(),Text=i.ToString()});

 var model=new ViewModel{ Year=2021,Years= years});

 return View(model);
}
```

and view GetYear.cshtml

```
@model ViewModel
.....
 <select class="form-control"  asp-for="@Model.Year" asp-items="@Model.Years"></select>
```

Answer (score 3):

MVC does not prescribe that everything must be a class or enum. It makes no sense to have enum members representing years.

What were you going to name them, `Y2021` and then strip the `Y`? Or use their underlying numeric value, ignoring the label?

Just use a loop and an integer, like you do now.